# Custom segue to sibling view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, segue, ios9

I have 3 pages that should segue like so...

```
  ,-(1)-> Home <-(2)-,
  v                  v
Login ----(3)---> Register
```

*where `Login -> Register` segue is triggered by a "Don't have an account? Register now." button, you know, something like that... Also, mind the unidirectional arrow.*

**All segues are already implemented, except for one: when a segue with this order is triggered:**

```
Home -> Login -> Register -> Home
```

*where `Register -> Home` is triggered via back button.*

Basically, I need to know how to set `Register`'s `parentViewController` to `Home` so that when the `Back` button is pressed (which then calls `performSegueWithIdentifier` with my custom unwind segue), `Register` would then unwind to `Home`.

Based on the segue order chain mentioned above, `Register` unwinds to a dismissed `Login`, I believe.

P.S. I'm using the **interface builder** for the views.

**P.S. `Login` and `Register` are presented MODALLY, so they go on top of `Home`**

Comment: can u explain in detail with example like am the user...

Comment: You can call "self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)" if   its in the same hierarchy OR "presentViewController" and add the custom animation to it.

Comment: @AAA I believe I already explained it enough

Comment: @Karlos I'm not using `navigationController` for this one

Answer (score 1):

To add custom animation to present view controller using custom animation
You have call `self. performAnimation()` function on your back button of Registration and Login. The below code is for Registration and Home screen.

```
  // This function will be present in your Registration viewController
  func performAnimation() {
        //Your storyboard name
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let YourNavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourNavigationController") as! UINavigationController


        let  mainVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourHomeScreenIdentifier") as! YourHomeScreen

        initialNavigationController.viewControllers = [mainVC]


        self.presentViewController(YourNavigationController,  animated: false, completion: nil)
        (mainVC as YourHomeScreen).fromRegisterSelector()
    }




   //These function or line of code should be present in your Home viewController
    func fromRegisterSelector()
    {
        hasComeHereFromRegVC = true
    } 


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if hasComeHereFromRegVC
        {
            addSignInViewAndAnimateIt()
        }

    }    

    func addSignInViewAndAnimateIt()
    {
        hasComeHereFromRegVC = false

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let mainNavigationController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

        let RegVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegViewController") as! YourRegViewController
        mainNavigationController.viewControllers = [RegVC]

        self.view.addSubview(mainNavigationController.view)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(mainNavigationController.view)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            // To change the screen sliding direction change the origin.x to origin.y and frame.width to frame.height in the line below
            mainNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x += self.view.frame.width

            }) { (finished) -> Void in

                mainNavigationController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @ton: I have updated the answer for you model transition. To change the screen sliding direction change the origin.x to origin.y and frame.width to frame.height. Try it and let me know the results.